# on hover slide panel from right and mouseout slide back

Tags: jquery, html, css, panel, slide

Hi guys i have tried what you had given to me.. but what wrong am i doing
see my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/Ej5k8/

```
 body {

position: relative;
min-height: 3000px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
top: 0;
font-family:'proximanova-regular', sans-serif;
 }
```

when you hover over the right top button the silde keep flickering and not like the example i want on  http://yahoo.tumblr.com/

Comment: What do you want to do on mouse out ?

Comment: this is the effect im trying to achieve http://yahoo.tumblr.com/ hover your mouse on tumblr button on top right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not do it in pure CSS?

```css
* { margin: 0; }

#panel {
  position: fixed;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  right: -300px;
          transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
#panel:hover {
  right: 0px;
}

#panelCaller {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 300px;        /* same as #panel width */
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">

  <div id="panelCaller">OPTIONS</div>

  <h2>Panel</h2>
  <p>Content...</p>
  
</div>
```

Otherwise in jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/vVSJz/156/

```
var $pCont = $("#panel-content");
$pCont.width(0);
$("#panel").hover(function(ev){
    $pCont.stop().animate({width: ev.type=="mouseenter" ? 500 : 0}, 700);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `jQuery` hover for something so simple

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/vVSJz/154/

```
$("#panel").hover(function(){
    $("#panel-content").animate({width: '600'}, 500);
  },function(){
  $("#panel-content").animate({width: '30'}, 500);
});
```

***EDITED***

To stop the effect repating use `.stop()` after the last call.

```
$("#panel").hover(function(){
        $("#panel-content").animate({width: '600'}, 500);
      },function(){
      $("#panel-content").animate({width: '30'}, 500);
      $("#panel-content").animate({width: '30'}, 500).stop();
    });
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/vVSJz/158/

Comment: if i hover and leave for several times it does the animation for a long ti,e. I know ou need to use something called .stopPropagation how to use that

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches, one of them is to use jquery `mouseleave` the same way you have used `mouseenter`.
So in conjuction with your code you can try the following,

http://jsfiddle.net/PrN9g/

```
$("#panel-tab").mouseenter(function (event) {
                $('#panel-content').stop(true,true);
                $("#panel-tab").stop(true);
                event.stopPropagation();
                showIfNotVisible("#panel-content");
            });
            $('#panel-content').mouseleave(function(){
                $("#panel-tab").stop(true,true);
                $('#panel-content').stop(true);
                                    hideIfNotHidden(this);                 

                                                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay Edited my answer and added animation, which is smooth. Take a look.
I knew I was doing something wrong.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vVSJz/157/)

***JS:***

```
  $(function () {
        $("#panel-content").hide();

        $("#panel-tab").mouseenter(function () {
            $("#panel-content").show();
            $("#panel-content").animate({width:'300px'},'slow');
            $(this).addClass("hidden");
        });

     $("#panel-content").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({width: "1px"}, "slow", function()
        {
            $("#panel-tab").removeClass( "hidden" );
            $(this).hide();
        });
     });

    });
```

***CSS**

```
  .hidden{
    display:none;
   }
```

In short, you forgot the `mouseleave function`. Also, I would suggest cleaning your code and remove unnecessary things that are not required.